# Finding $\operatorname{Im}T$ - Linear Algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Regarding :
$T: \mathbb{R}^{n+1} \to \mathbb{R}^{n}, T(x_1,...,x_{n+1})=(x_1+x_{n+1},x_2,...,x_n) $
I need to find $\ker T$ and $\operatorname{Im}T.$
To find $\operatorname{Im}T,$ I want to take a spanning set of $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$, which will be $(e_1,e_2,...,e_n,e_{n+1}),$ and by a theorem. I can say that :
$\operatorname{Im}T=\operatorname{span}\{T(e_1),...,T(e_{n+1})\}=\operatorname{span}\{e_1+e_{n+1},e_2\ldots, e_{n}\}$
But now I have a problem, because those vectors doesn't belong to $\mathbb{R}^n.$
Any help ?
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that:

- $T(e_1)=(1,0,0,\ldots,0)$;
- $T(e_2)=(0,1,0,0,\ldots,0)$;
- $\vdots$
- $T(e_n)=(0,0,0,\ldots,0,1)$;
- $T(e_{n+1})=(1,0,0,\ldots,0)$.

So $\operatorname{Im}T=\Bbb R^n$.

Comment: Thank you so much! So, $(1,0,0,...,0)$ contains $n$ elements, is that correct? How can I know that for sure?

Comment: Actually, it is *one* element of $\Bbb R^n$. It has $n$ components, if that's what you want to know.

Comment: Alright. One more question, why $T(e_{n+1})=(1,0,0,...,0)$?

Comment: Because\begin{align}T(e_{n+1})&=T(0,0,\ldots,0,1)\\&=(0+1,0,0,\ldots,0)\\&=(1,0,0,\ldots,0).\end{align}

Comment: Awesome, thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Your computation of $Te_1,Te_2,..$ is wrong. $Te_1=T(1,0,0..,0)=(1,0,0..,0)$; In fact $Te_i=e_i$ for $i \leq n$ and $Te_{n+1}=e_1$. Now it should be clear that $T$ is surjective.

If $Tx=0$ then $x_2=x_3,...,x_n=0$ and $x_1+x_{n+1}=0$. So the kernel consists of vectors $x$ such that $x_1+x_{n+1}=0$. (It is the one dimensional space  spanned by $(1,0,0,..,0,-1)$).

Comment: Thank yo Kavi! Do you mean that $T(1,0,0,...,0)$ contains $n+1$ elements, while $(1,0,0,...,0)$ contains $n$?

Comment: @MathLover Yes. When I write $Tx=y$ it is understood that $x \in \mathbb R^{n+1}$ and $y \in \mathbb R^{n}$

Comment: Cool, thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

$T(e_i)$ belongs to $\mathbb R^n$, since that is the codomain of $T$, hence you get $\mathbb R^n$ for your image.  There are a number of ways to see this.  For instance, you could note that $T(e_i)=\hat {e_i}$, where $\hat{e_i}$ are the standard basis vectors for $\mathbb R^n$.

Alternatively, you could note that the kernel is one-dimensional, and use Rank-Nullity.

Comment: Cool! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

You have to distinguish between the vectors in a basis of $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ and those in $\mathbb{R}^n$. If you “prime” the ones in the codomain, you have
$$
T(e_1)=e_1',\quad T(e_2)=e_2',\quad \dots,\quad T(e_n)=e_n',\quad T(e_{n+1})=e_1'
$$

Thus you see that $\{e_1',e_2',\dots,e_n'\}$ is contained in the image, so the linear map is surjective. Thus, by rank-nullity, its kernel has dimension $1$ and it suffices to find a nonzero vector in the kernel, which is, for instance, $e_1-e_{n+1}$, so the kernel is generated by $e_1-e_{n+1}$.

Comment: Thank you so much! :)